# How to select "nearest left" and "nearesr right" values from a dataframe using condition?

Tags: python, pandas, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataframe with several columns and rows.
E.g. minimal example to reproduce:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'tof': {4875: 553.347572418771, 4876: 554.4911639867169, 4877: 556.2920840265602, 4878: 560.4059228421942, 4879: 560.7254631042018, 4880: 563.528024491697, 4881: 566.9995989172061, 4882: 570.7775523817776, 4883: 572.0685266789887}, 'E': {4875: 21.390025636898983, 4876: 21.301354836365054, 4877: 21.16283071077996, 4878: 20.85142476306085, 4879: 20.82752461774972, 4880: 20.61965532001513, 4881: 20.366451134218167, 4882: 20.096164210524464, 4883: 20.005036194577794}})
```

```
             tof          E
4875  553.347572  21.390026
4876  554.491164  21.301355
4877  556.292084  21.162831
4878  560.405923  20.851425
4879  560.725463  20.827525
4880  563.528024  20.619655
4881  566.999599  20.366451
4882  570.777552  20.096164
4883  572.068527  20.005036
```

I need to select 2 closest points (rows) using some provided value E_provided.

E.g. `E_provided = 20.83`

closest point(row) left to some value of E_search = closest_left gives

```
4879  560.725463  20.827525
```

closest point(row) right to some value of E_search = closest_right

```
4878  560.405923  20.851425
```

I understand that it's simple task, and I need to calculate some difference between df2['E']-E_provided and use additional conditions, but I don't get how to do it :)

I have tried this one:

```
df2.iloc[(df['E']-E_provided).abs().argsort()[:2]]
```

But it works incorrect because there are points that are close to the provided value just from one side, e.g. for `E_provided == 20.1` it will output 2 nearest points both of them are left to E_provided value:

```
4882  570.777552  20.096164
4883  572.068527  20.005036
```

While I need to find:

```
4881  566.999599  20.366451
4882  570.777552  20.096164
```

Answer (score 1):

Find values greater than/less than your value:

```
E_provided = 20.83
mask = df2.E.gt(E_provided)
```

Use this to get the closet from each direction:

```
above_id = df2.loc[mask, 'E'].sub(E_provided).abs().idxmin()
below_id = df2.loc[~mask, 'E'].sub(E_provided).abs().idxmin()
```

Now we can look up those two rows:

```
out = df2.loc[[above_id, below_id]]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
             tof          E
4878  560.405923  20.851425
4879  560.725463  20.827525
```

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant, but working solution:

```
lower_ind = signal[signal['E'] < real_coord]['E'].idxmax()
upper_ind = signal[signal['E'] > real_coord]['E'].idxmin()

indx_list = [lower_ind, upper_ind]

out = df2.loc[indx_list]
print(out)
```